# C++ map matrix column into rank - bit manipulations

Tags: c++, matrix, c++11, bit-manipulation, transpose

I've got (binary) matrices represented by uint64_t (from C++11). And I'd like to be able to efficiently map from any column into first rank. For example

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

uint64_t matrice = 0x4040400040400040uLL;
uint64_t matrice_2 = map(matrice, ColumnEnum::Column2);

1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

matrice_2 contains 0xED00000000000000uLL;

Comment: Why not just... iterate through and do that? Have you tried anything?

Comment: The simplest solution will be iterate uint8_t by uint8_t and check 7th(in this example) bit by logical and with a proper mask and generate output matrix. But I doubt if it is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. I really enjoyed the hacking.  Here is my solution:

```
uint64_t map(uint64_t x, int column)
{
  x = (x >> (7 - column)) & 0x0101010101010101uLL;
  x = (x | (x >> 7)) & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FFuLL;
  x = (x | (x >> 14))& 0x000000FF000000FFuLL;
  x = (x | (x >> 28))& 0x00000000000000FFuLL;
  return x << 56;
}
```

A working example can be found at [ideone](http://ideone.com/DMHBo1), where the call is really `map(matrice, ColumnEnum::Column2)`.

Comment: It's look great! Is there similar way to go back? Some kind of map from first rank to the previus column?

Answer (score 3):

A nice little riddle. Here is a reasonably readable version:

```
matrice = (matrice >> (8ull - column)) & 0x0101010101010101ull;
uint64_t result((  ((matrice >>  0ul)  & 0x01ull)
                 | ((matrice >>  7ul)  & 0x02ull)
                 | ((matrice >> 14ull) & 0x04ull)
                 | ((matrice >> 21ull) & 0x08ull)
                 | ((matrice >> 28ull) & 0x10ull)
                 | ((matrice >> 35ull) & 0x20ull)
                 | ((matrice >> 42ull) & 0x40ull)
                 | ((matrice >> 49ull) & 0x80ull)) << 56ull);
```

Answer (score 1):

First define bitmask for every column:

```
uint64_t columns[8] = {
  0x8080808080808080uLL,
  0x4040404040404040uLL,
  //...
  0x0101010101010101uLL
};
```

by applying column  bitmask to your "matrice" you get only this column:

```
uint64_t col1 = matrice & columns[1]; // second column - rest is empty
```

by shifting you can get only first column case:

```
uint64_t col0 = (col1 << 1); // second column - rest is empty
//                       ^ this number is just zero based index of column,,,
```

Now first bit is on right place - just set the next 7 bits:

```
 col0 |= (col0 & (1 << 55)) << 7; // second bit...
 // ....
```

Or just use `std::bitset<64>`, I would do....